# CSS Stylesheet Not Showing on Landing Page

Tags: html, css, templates

I'm creating a landing page for work using a html template, I've taken this template here (www.switchonbook.com) and am editing it for a different product.

Regardless of what I do the second CSS won't show. I have
-Tested the CSS and the HTML through testers online, no problems
-Tried changing the location of the files
-Compared the code to the original code of the landing page

Here is the code I am using for the new landing page;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?      family=Open+Sans:300italic,400,300,600,700' rel='stylesheet'>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>Switch On: Your DIY Toolkit</title>
<meta name="description" content="Switch On: Your DIY Toolkit">


<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.ripeandready.com/wordpress/wp-  content/uploads/2015/03/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="http://www.ripeandready.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">

<link href="http://switchonbook.com/css/styles.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://switchonbook.com/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" >
</head>
<body>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's working fine for me. What do you mean by saying that the CSS "won't show"?

Comment: What do you see? I just get a blank page, if I remove the second stylesheet I get a jumbled mess of text. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. In the code you posted, nothing should appear, because there is nothing after the opening `<body>` tag. The stylesheets will style the content in the `<body>`, but they don't add content of their own. When I said "It's working fine," I meant that the stylesheets are loading properly.

Comment: I have a full landing page using the code of the link, except all I get when I load the page is a blue loading swirly thing, as opposed to any content.  When I remove the main stylesheet from the code I can see the content of the page but all jumbled.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors in your code. For instance, here:

```
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?      family=Open+Sans:300italic,400,300,600,700
```

There should not be spaces after the `?`. Similarly, there should not be a space here after the `-`:

```
http://www.ripeandready.com/wordpress/wp-  content/uploads/2015/03/favicon.png
```

Also, you do not have closing `</body>` and `</html>` tags.

Comment: Thanks! Have fixed but still no difference I'm afraid :(